# Migrating Django project from MySQL to Postgres

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, database-migration

We are moving a big Django project from MySQL to Postgres, and after we fixed all the tests is now time to actually migrate the whole database.

I found this very nice project to do that:
http://pgloader.io/

And the way it works is that it first drop all the indexes/constraints, copy the data and then restore them.

However then I found this issue:

https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/400

which means I can't exactly rely on the indexes/constraints recreated, and have to handle it myself instead.

So then I had another idea, I could simply:

1. generate an empty migrated Postgres database
2. dump it to SQL
3. run pgloader making it drop everything but not restore them
4. use the db dump (after removing the CREATE TABLE other statements I don't need) to restore everything correctly

I think this should work but it seems quite brittle and also will not be as fast as pgloader which uses concurrency a lot to make the process much faster.

Any other idea or approach I could try?
Thanks